# Vlan & subinterface

Tags: 14.04

Is VLAN tag and subinterface number is same or they are different. I want to access a Vlan enabled device with Vlan Id 10, so should I create a subinterface of 10 in eth0?

Answer (score 4):

Adding a vlan tagged interface will create a new interface tagged. So no need of creating a new sub interface for the vlan, as it will be created automatically.

```
$ ifconfig eth0
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  Endereço de HW 00:24:8c:55:45:8a  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Métrica:1
          pacotes RX:0 erros:0 descartados:0 excesso:0 quadro:0
          Pacotes TX:0 erros:0 descartados:0 excesso:0 portadora:0
          colisões:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B) TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
          IRQ:19 Endereço de E/S:0xdead 

$ sudo vconfig add eth0 64
$ sudo ifconfig eth0.64 10.0.0.1 netmask 255.255.255.0
$ ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  Endereço de HW 00:24:8c:55:45:8a  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Métrica:1
          pacotes RX:0 erros:0 descartados:0 excesso:0 quadro:0
          Pacotes TX:0 erros:0 descartados:0 excesso:0 portadora:0
          colisões:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B) TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
          IRQ:19 Endereço de E/S:0xdead 

eth0.64   Link encap:Ethernet  Endereço de HW 00:24:8c:55:45:8a  
          inet end.: 10.0.0.1  Bcast:10.0.0.255  Masc:255.255.255.0
          endereço inet6: fe80::224:8cff:fe55:458a/64 Escopo:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Métrica:1
          pacotes RX:0 erros:0 descartados:0 excesso:0 quadro:0
          Pacotes TX:0 erros:0 descartados:25 excesso:0 portadora:0
          colisões:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B) TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```